# What happens to conservation laws if the spatial variable is complex?

Tags: conservation-laws, complex-numbers

This is more of a conceptual question. Normally a conservation law will look something like

$$\frac{\partial j}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=0\tag{1}$$

where $x$ is typically a real-valued coordinate, or even $\nabla$ if we have a space with a few dimensions in it. It's then pretty easy to define an integral over $-\infty<x<\infty$ or over the surface, etc. which is a conserved quantity.

But let's say we're working in a two-dimensional space now, and we can change our coordinates from $(x,y)$ to $z=x+iy.$ If we wind up with an equation of the form

$$\frac{\partial j}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}=0,\tag{2}$$

does this give us conservation laws as well? It seems that it is difficult to define any integral over a surface which isn't trivial, because only poles of a complex function will contribute to a nonzero integral. But obviously, many functions in physics won't have poles - a two-dimensional fluid can often be described with a complex velocity, for example, and this is going to be analytic in most cases. We could think of charges and the like as being poles, but it's much harder to see how we get anything like momentum, angular momentum, and so on.

What can we say about the conserved quantities of the system when the variable is complex now instead of real?

Comment: Your second equation is not the direct analogue of the first one -- you will need $G=F_1+\text{i} F_2$ and some complex conjugates. In general, you can always reformulate two-dimensional real problems in terms of complex numbers, but then tzhe functions and equations will include $z$ and $\bar z$, i.e. they will not be holomorphic. Your question may apply to holomorphic quantities, as they appear e.g. in 2d conformal field theory (string worldsheet).

Comment: Just for the sake of argument, supposing that it's much easier to work with complex variables and we have everything analytic in terms of $z$ and $t,$ what would typically then be done to actually derive conserved quantities from that equation? Is it possible or convenient to do this without just redoing everything in terms of real variables?

Comment: Well, I only recall that in 2d CFT, everything is indeed holomorphic, so you generally work in complex formulation. Maybe you can look up CFT, Virasoro algebra etc; these will be in books on string theory or loads of lecture notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For each [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation)
   $$ \sum_{\mu = 0}^n\frac{\partial J^{\mu}_a}{\partial x^{\mu}}~=~0, \tag{A}$$
   one can define a conserved quantity
   $$ Q_a(t)~:=~\int_V \! d^nx~ J^0_a(\vec{x}, t). \tag{B}$$
2. *OP's example:*  Let $J^{\mu}=J^{\mu}_1 +i J^{\mu}_2$ be a complex current, and introduce a complex space coordinate $z=x^1+ix^2$, i.e. $n=2$. OP's continuity equation (2) is of the form  (A) if we use Dolbeault derivatives
   $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial z}~=~\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2} \right), \qquad\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}~=~\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2} \right).\tag{C}$$

Comment: This is interesting. Are you able to point me in a direction where I can get more substantial information about these derivative operators so that I can actually use these for worked examples/practical calculation of conserved quantities? Thanks.

Comment: I added eq. (C) as a start.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that was the name. In that case, you mean to say that you can just obtain an equation  of the form $\partial_t\rho+\partial_zJ_z+\partial_{\overline{z}}J_{\overline{z}}=0$ and then just take an area integral over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.